# Suppose $f$ is in $C([0,1])$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Show that $f$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials with $p_n(0) =p_n(1) = 0$ for all $n$.

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, approximation, approximation-theory

I am stuck on how to start. My idea is the following but I am not sure how it will lead to anything:

1. We know that because $f$ is continuous function on real interval $[a,b]$, then for all $\epsilon$, there is polynomial $p$ such that for all $x\in[a,b]$, we have that $\left | f(x)-p(x) \right |< \epsilon $ by Weierstrass' Theorem.
2. Construct Taylor series for $f(x)$, call it $p(x)$.
3. So $f(x)-p(x) =0 $ so it will clearly be less than any choice of $\epsilon$.

But, how do the conditions on $f$, that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ come into play? Am I even on right track?

Comment: Just add a linear polynomial $q$ so that $\tilde p = p+q$ has $\tilde p(0) = \tilde p(1) = 0$. you need to check that this new polynomial is still closed to $f$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'closed' here?

Comment: I think he meant to say that your new polynomial is _close_ to $f$ still. In other words, your modification to the sequence of polynomials given to you by Weierstrass' theorem still converge to $f$ uniformly.

Comment: Hmmm still not quite seeing what the $q$ is for. I am seeing it as that this polynomial $q$ we are adding to $p$, results that $\tilde{p(0)} =p(0)+q(0)$. By the assumption, $f(0)=f(1)=0$ implies $p(0)=p(1)=0$ due to $p(x)=f(x)$. Hence, for $\tilde{p(0)} = 0$, $q(0)=q(1)=0$ but now what? What is purpose of $q$?

Comment: $p(x)$ is not equal to $f(x)$. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, the Weierstrass approximation theorem gives you a polynomial $p$ such that $\left| p(x) - f(x) \right| < \varepsilon$ for all $x \in \left[ 0, 1 \right]$. Note that $f$ and $p$ aren't necessarily equal, and you're not guaranteed that $p(0) = p(1) = 0$ either. To remedy the last part, you need to add some polynomial $q$ to $p$ so that $\tilde{p} := q + p$ satisfies $\tilde{p}(0) = \tilde{p}(1) = 0$, but $\tilde{p}$ is still sufficiently "close" to $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is a trick: since $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, we have $|f(x)|\leq M$ for any $x\in[0,1]$.
Let $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2M}}\sqrt{f(x)+2M}$, which is also a continuous function. By the Weierstrass approximation theorem there is some polynomial $g_n(x)$ such that $\left|g(x)-g_n(x)\right|\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for any $x\in[0,1]$.
$$ h_n(x) = g_n(x)+(1-g_n(0))(1-x)+(1-g_n(1))x $$
is a polynomial such that $h_n(0)=h_n(1)=1$ and $|g(x)-h_n(x)|\leq \frac{2}{n}$ for any $x\in[0,1]$.
$$ f_n(x) = 2M h_n(x)^2 - 2M $$
is a polynomial such that $f_n(0)=f_n(1)=0$ and $|f(x)-f_n(x)|\leq\frac{5M}{n}$ for any $x\in[0,1]$.

---

If $f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$ and $1$ we may simply approximate $\frac{f(x)}{x(1-x)}$ through polynomials $p_n(x)$, then consider $f_n(x)=x(1-x)p_n(x)$. Of course this approach does not work if $f(x)=\sqrt{x(1-x)}$, for instance. And in general not every continuous function agrees with its Taylor series at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$. Let $q(x)=p(x)-p(0)-x(p(1)-p(0)$. The $q$ is polynomial with $q(0)=0$ and $q(1)=0$. Also $|f(x)-q(x)|<|f(x)-p(x)|+|p(0)|+|p(1)-p(0)| \leq  \ 4\epsilon $. ($ |p(0)| \leq |f(0)-p(0)|+|f(0)| <\epsilon$ etc).